# Woocommerce Archive page: Thumbnail effect on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How can I achieve the following effect:

[image]

Version A (for screen above 768 px)
When the **cursor is over** the product thumbnail -> show div with the "Add to cart" button.

Version 2 (for screen below 768 px)
When I **click** on a product thumbnail -> show div with "Add to cart" button. When clicking on a product thumbnail, do not take the customer to the product page.